# Хвостовая рекурсия и аккумуляторы в Haskell

Tags: функции, математика, рекурсия, haskell, функциональное-программирование

Как работает хвостовая рекурсия и аккумуляторы в Haskell на конкретном примере, а именно реализация Чисел Фибоначчи:

```
fibonacci' :: Integer -> Integer
fibonacci' n = helper 0 1 n 

helper :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer -> Integer
helper first second 0 = first
helper first second n | n > 0 = helper (first + second) first (n - 1)
                      | n < 0 = helper second (first - second) (n + 1)
                      | otherwise = first
```

Как это работает вообщем в данном языке? К примеру если мы вводим fibonacci 6, то почему мы получаем 8, с помощью подстановки? что происходит (пошагово) за "кулисами"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

На примере 6 (надеюсь, что верно понял вопрос):

```
helper 0 1 6 -- изначально вызываем
helper 1 0 5 -- в первом аргументе сумма первого и второго предыдущего 0+1 , а 0 из первого предыдущего - во второй аргумент = 0
helper 1 1 4 -- в первом сумма 1+0, а во второй идёт значение из первого = 1
helper 2 1 3 -- в первом сумма 1+1, а во второй берём значение из первого = 1
helper 3 2 2 -- в первом сумма 2+1, а во второй = 2
helper 5 3 1 -- в первом сумма 3+2, а во второй = 3
helper 8 5 0 -- т.к. значение третьего аргумента равно нулю, то получаем результат из первого = 8
```